# Compact Operators on Hilbert Space & Orthogonal Projections

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, orthogonality, compact-operators

I am studying Functional Analysis and Spectral Theory and I came across this definition in the Wikipedia article [Compact Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator) that I didn't study in class:

A *compact operator* on a Hilbert $H$ space is written in the form: $T=\sum_{n\geq 1}{\lambda_{n}\langle f_n,\cdot \rangle g_n}$ where $\{f_{1},f_{2},\ldots \}$ and $\{g_{1},g_{2},\ldots \}$ are orthonormal sets (not necessarily complete), and $\lambda _{1},\lambda _{2},\ldots$ is a sequence of positive numbers with limit zero.
I have a couple of questions:

- Any hints on how to prove the existence of these sequences?
- Does this have any relation with orthogonal projections?
- How can we define an orthogonal projection in a Hilbert space?
- Are they projecting to finite subspaces of $H$? If so, what are these finite subspaces?
- If $T$ is self-adjoint, would it be easier to prove that?

Comment: Which Wikipedia article is this from?

Comment: Compact Operators https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator

Comment: check out this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Bounded_operators_on_Hilbert_spaces